# Problem with reordering items in a bootstrap-select control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, c#-4.0

I am using [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select) control for multiple item select and reorder item, but it is not working correctly. I drag item1 from position 1 to 2 position, then select item1, but item2 is selected. If I select item2 then it automatically selects item1.

In this image, Item Code move 1 to 2 then I am unselect Item Code but unselect "Item Description" and if Item Code move1 to 2 then I am unselect "Item Description" but unselect Item Code

[image]

**My Control Is**

```js
/* My Control Initialization */

$("#columname").selectpicker({
  liveSearch: true
});

/* Sorting initialization */

$(".dropdown-toggle").on("click", function() {
  $(".inner").sortable();
});
```

```html
<select id="columname" name="columname" class="form-control" required multiple data-selected-text-format="count">
  <option data-icon="fas fa-ellipsis-v" selected="">Item Code</option>
  <option data-icon="fas fa-ellipsis-v" selected="">Item Description</option>
  <option data-icon="fas fa-ellipsis-v" selected="">Item Category</option>
  <option data-icon="fas fa-ellipsis-v" selected="">Item Class</option<option data-icon="fas fa-ellipsis-v" selected="">GL Code-Income</option>
  <option data-icon="fas fa-ellipsis-v" selected="">GL Code-Expense</option>
  <option data-icon="fas fa-ellipsis-v" selected="">Item Status</option>
  <option data-icon="fas fa-ellipsis-v" selected="">Status</option>
</select>
```